# Multiple Domains/Sites connected to the same Database BUT one root folder for the UPLOADS, how?

Tags: database, codeigniter, multiple-domains

I have multiple domains/sites that are connected to the same database and that are install on the same Dedicated Server. However, I like to have ONLY one root folder for the UPLOADS (like images, contracts, etc.) Example: right now if I register as an user on www.site1.com and I upload images, I am able to see the images uploaded to www.site1.com BUT NOT on www.site2.com or Vice-Versa.

Each domain has its own Applications folder as well as Admins. They share everything except for the UPLOADS, I don't know why but images are not been shared correctly. These are examples of how the UPLOADS are called in different files.

```
$config['base_url']     = site_url('performers/page/');

$upload_path    = 'uploads/performers/' . $performer->id;

@unlink(BASEPATH . '../uploads/performers/' . $photo->performer_id . '/' . $photo->name_on_disk);
```

ANY THOUGHTS?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating one folder for your uploads and create symlinks that point to that folder for every domain